# Can you have 2 different time ranges in the same query?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I want to run the following query:

```
( requests
| where timestamp > ago(-24h)
| summarize day = avg(duration) 
)
| union ( requests
| where timestamp > ago(-10m)
| summarize now = avg(duration)
)
```

I want to get the avg request duration of the last day and of the last 10 min.
I do it now in 2 different queries, but I like to have them in 1 query for performance.

When I run this query I get no response, I see the day and the now column, but it has no value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from a query language perspective, what you're doing is valid and should work.

you should verify if you really intend to use the minus (`-`) sign in your call to the `ago()` function.

if you want the result in a single row, you can also use a `join` instead of a `union`

```
print ago(24h), ago(-24h)
```

will output:

```
| print_0                     | print_1                     |
|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| 2019-04-03 15:04:24.0178923 | 2019-04-05 15:04:24.0178923 |
```

and:

```
let requests = datatable(timestamp:datetime, duration:timespan)
[
    datetime(2019-03-03 14:00), 123s,
    datetime(2019-03-03 15:00), 12s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 16:00), 13s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 17:00), 456s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 18:00), 56s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 19:00), 45s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 20:00), 43s,
    datetime(2019-04-04 16:55), 77s,
]
;
requests
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| summarize day = avg(duration) 
| union ( 
    requests
    | where timestamp > ago(10m)
    | summarize now = avg(duration)
)
```

will output:

```
| day      | now      |
|----------|----------|
| 00:01:55 |          |
|          | 00:01:17 |
```

and:

```
let requests = datatable(timestamp:datetime, duration:timespan)
[
    datetime(2019-03-03 14:00), 123s,
    datetime(2019-03-03 15:00), 12s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 16:00), 13s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 17:00), 456s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 18:00), 56s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 19:00), 45s,
    datetime(2019-04-03 20:00), 43s,
    datetime(2019-04-04 16:55), 77s,
]
;
requests
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| summarize day = avg(duration) by dummy = 1
| join kind=inner 
( 
    requests
    | where timestamp > ago(10m)
    | summarize now = avg(duration) by dummy = 1
) on dummy
| project day, now
```

will output:

```
| day      | now      |
|----------|----------|
| 00:01:55 | 00:01:17 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turned out that it had to do with the minus (-) in the ago() function. Also thanks for the join alternative